# How can I parse the content (result) of twitter search page using Java?

Tags: java, html, twitter

I'm trying to parse the HTML content of a search page of twitter, i.e : https://twitter.com/search?q=unforgiven&src=typd.
I want to extract all tweets from this page.

The page isnt fully loaded as new content always shows up if we reach the end of the page.
[image: Screenshot]

Thanks !

Comment: You can use Twitter API, search for it

Comment: Thanks ! but the search API is too limited, I need a (very) large amount of tweet in order to use them as an input for a data mining algorithm :)

Comment: Twitter API requires phone number registration for creating apps now(tokens and etc.), even for a simple GET request. After a long research, I decided to try XML parsing of Twitter feed but it turns out Twitter stopped that service too. I found [this](http://tweet-2-rss.appspot.com/#) converter in the hopes of continuing my research but Twitter made them stop too. I'm not sure why they are forcing their hands this much but I can say that some privacy issue is going on.

Comment: However, you can use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parsing](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) if you still want to get the contents.